# Tasked to convert XML file into JSON file using Python to be imported into MongoDB

Tags: python, json, xml

I have beginner and intermediate python knowledge and have tried many different codes to complete my task but ended up with a different result from what I am seeking. I am given an XML file and am tasked to convert it into a JSON file using python. The format should be so that each line is a dictionary and there are no commas in between lines so that it can be imported into MongoDB.

The JSON file should look like something like this:

{dictionary}

{dictionary}

...

{dictionary}

The XML file is named 'uwm.file' and this is what the first 64 lines look like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>

<root>
<course_listing>
  <note>#</note>
  <course>216-088</course>
  <title>NEW STUDENT ORIENTATION</title>
  <credits>0</credits>
  <level>U</level>
  <restrictions>; ; REQUIRED OF ALL NEW STUDENTS. PREREQ: NONE</restrictions>
   <section_listing>
      <section_note></section_note>
      <section>Se 001</section>
      <days>W</days>
      <hours>
          <start>1:30pm</start>
          <end></end>
      </hours>
      <bldg_and_rm>
          <bldg>BUS</bldg>
          <rm>S230</rm>
      </bldg_and_rm>
      <instructor>Gusavac</instructor>
      <comments>9 WKS BEGINNING WEDNESDAY, 9/6/00 </comments>
   </section_listing>
   <section_listing>
      <section_note></section_note>
      <section>Se 002</section>
      <days>F</days>
      <hours>
          <start>11:30am</start>
          <end></end>
      </hours>
      <bldg_and_rm>
          <bldg>BUS</bldg>
          <rm>S171</rm>
      </bldg_and_rm>
      <instructor>Gusavac</instructor>
      <comments>9 WKS BEGINNING FRIDAY, 9/8/00 </comments>
   </section_listing>
</course_listing>

<course_listing>
  <note>#</note>
  <course>216-293</course>
  <title>BUSINESS ETHICS</title>
  <credits>3</credits>
  <level>U</level>
  <restrictions>; ; PREREQ: NONE</restrictions>
   <section_listing>
      <section_note></section_note>
      <section>Se 001</section>
      <days>R</days>
      <hours>
          <start>2:30pm</start>
          <end>5:10pm</end>
      </hours>
      <bldg_and_rm>
          <bldg>BUS</bldg>
          <rm>S230</rm>
      </bldg_and_rm>
      <instructor>Silberg</instructor>
   </section_listing>
</course_listing>
```

Comment: Will any old JSON file do, or do you want a very specific JSON output?

Comment: The XML file has a bit over 2000 documents and I just want to be able to have all the documents to be displayed on MongoDB instead of 1 document.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the xmltodict package to convert the xml to a dictionary, and then dump it to a json file.

```
import xmltodict
import json

with open("uwm.file") as xml_file:
    data_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_file.read())

json_data = json.dumps(data_dict)
with open("uwm.json", "w") as json_file:
        json_file.write(json_data)
```